# Explanation of Base Class (Flash) and inheritance

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a MovieClip called PopUp where I wrote some code.

I need to make another MovieClip that uses pretty much the same code...can I just use the PopUp class as the base class for my other MovieClip?

They look different but they have the same instances on the stage and stuff.

Comment: Are you modifying the code within the PopUp when you create your next PopUp?  How much code are you planning on reusing and how much code would you be changing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just create a new class called PopUpBase, and let your new MC's extend that class. Generally changing the base class in the IDE can cause some problems, so it's best practice not to, but to create classes (and .as files) for each MC that needs code.

Depending on what you're doing with this, it might be okay just to change the base classes to PopUpBase (in the IDE) :)

Comment: Thanks I will do this...just wondering, why DOES changing the base class in the IDE cause problems?

Comment: Can't give you a precise answer. I remember having problems with MC's having other base classes when I needed to preload my SWF.